# Generators of $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I was wondering about the following (possibly stupid) question: if $S$ is a one element (ring) generator set of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, $S$ must consist of a linear polynomial in $X$ (= degree $1$). Is the same true about $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$ ? So, if $S$ is an $m$ element generator set of $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$, does it consist of degree $1$ polynomials ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Do you mean generators as a ring, or as a $\Bbb Z$ module?

Comment: @GregoryGrant:  $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ is a *ring* and no forgetful functor is applied here. $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ *is not* a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Well, it *is* a $\mathbb Z$-module, but that structure is not the one being used in this question.

Comment: No. It has an *underlying* $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and this is a different object. (I know that 90% of the current literature ignores this, because this is claimed to be no problem. It is.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I thought all rings were abelian groups with extra structure.

Comment: That is absurd, I am sorry. Martin, you probably know that that sort of pedancy does not help anyone (that is why 99.9999999% of the universe "ignores" this) and, most importantly, does not help people here in particular.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Actually my experience is that a *lot of* confusion is caused because forgetful functors are ignored. Not ignoring them is not pedantic, it is very important. Not just for teaching by the way, also in research papers. But I know that I cannot convince you anyway.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Yes, the extra structure matters. A ring is a tuple $R=(A,\cdot,1)$, where $A$ is an abelian group, $\cdot$ is a multiplication map and $1$ is a unit, subject to some axioms. And $R \neq A$, obviously (not just for some set-theoretic reason, but also for "philosophical" reasons). And $A$ doesn't equal its underlying set, etc. It is important that any object has a fixed type (if you like type theory) resp. it belongs to a unique category, because this is what mathematicians actually need to work with and think about these objects.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Well that's fine, it's just that the theory of field extensions involve considering both ring and module finiteness conditions of field extensions.  No book I ever read says a ring is not a module, they just say a module is not necessarily a ring.  If one paid attention to the distinctions you are concerned about, wouldn't that make the exposition of the subject  more complicated than necessary?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: This is what one might think first. But in the end it will be simpler because the language will be unified, simplified, and above all: correct. I have gained some experience with this approach and I am convinced that it pays off. You might also look in my book on category theory which will be published in a couple of months, where no forgetful functor is ignored. Forgetful functors are interesting objects in their own right. A field hom. $K \to L$ is called finite if the *underlying $K$-module* is finite. So this information doesn't depend on the whole field structure of $L$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Are you suggesting that a fairly involved introduction to category theory should be a pre-requisite to studying something like Galois theory?  I think that would be a hard sell to most undergraduate math departments where it's already hard to get students prepared enough to study abstract algebra.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Of course not. But the distinction between a field and its underlying set, or its underlying additive group, for example, should be somewhat a prerequisite for studying Galois theory. One can speak of these "underlying objects" without any category theory, just using the good old definitions. And in algebraic geometry and topology it should be a prerequisite that a topological space is not just a set with a property, but that it is has an underlying set, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, $Y-X^2$, $X$ generate $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$.